# Baposter cls with defined papersize and text lettering

Tags: fontsize, posters, baposter

I'm trying to create a poster from the [`baposter`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/) class with definite font size (e.g. 70pt for title and 20pt for text lettering). Should I use `fontscale=1.0` and adjust the font size using `\fontsize` command manually?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `poster` library from `tcolorbox` rather than `baposter`. The `tcolorbox poster` library operates using the same construction principles implemented in `baposter`, but is arguably more flexible and is maintained.

This small example is built off the `poster` library documentation. It also shows how you can set the title and box content to a particular font size.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbposter}[
        coverage = {
            spread,
            interior style={top color=yellow,bottom color=yellow!50!red},
            watermark text={\LaTeX\ Poster},
            watermark color=yellow,
        },
        poster = {showframe,columns=4,rows=5},
        ]%
        \posterbox{name=title,column=1,span=3,below=top}{
        \resizebox{18cm}{!}{\bfseries\fontsize{70}{82}\selectfont Title} \\[3mm]
            \fontsize{48}{56}\selectfont Author}
        \posterbox[adjusted title=Core Algorithm]
        {name=Poster content,column=1,span=1,below=title}{\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont \lipsum[2]}
    \end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```